# Calculate date difference having a large range with PHP

Tags: php, date, datediff

I need to calculate the number of decades between 2 dates possible spanning form 1708 until today - the limitations are as far as I can gather are 1970/1901 within PHP native functions.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
$before  = new DateTime('1708-02-02');
$decades = $before->diff(new DateTime())->y / 10;
```

Comment: I'm stuck with 5.2 :-( - but that's great to know!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**Zend_Date**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.introduction.html). It's part of the Zend Framework but can be used standalone, you don't need to install the whole framework to use it. It can work with dates beyond 1901 if the `bcmath` extension is installed into your PHP. From Zend_date's [**theory of operation**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.definition.theory.html):

> This was only possible, because Zend_Date is not limited to UNIX timestamps nor integer values. The BCMath extension is required to support extremely large dates outside of the range Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. Additional, tiny math errors may arise due to the inherent limitations of float data types and rounding, unless using the BCMath extension.

I like to recommend Zend components because they are well-groomed, high-quality code. There are other solutions to this, though, for example using the [**mySQL date functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom method.

PHP date functions are based on the epoch ( 1969 ) so there won't be much help there.

If your just looking at years that is simple math

higher year - earlier year = years
years / 10 = decades.

If you mean decades from an even 01-10, 11-20 then you could do some rounding. (round early date up, later date down to nearest 10.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be date accurate. Thanks for the feedback though!