# Find days difference between two dates with range of thousands of year

Tags: php

How can we find days difference in PHP where dates may very from 1/1/1 to 1/1/1000000.

strtotime(), mktime(), date->diff() all these function are not be helpful as it is more then limit of Unix timestamp.

Comment: at least tell the reason for voting it down.

Comment: Most languages I've come across have a limit on the date range available, you may be best off writing your own algorithm.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what do you need this for?

Comment: My first thoughts.. you have to write your own algo.. obviously using bcmath. But hey check this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184554/1273830 zend!

Comment: I am working on some game app. for which I need that kind of function..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate date difference having a large range with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184506/calculate-date-difference-having-a-large-range-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [DateTime](https://www.php.net/DateTime) allows for dates in any periods of time. Even before unix.

Quite possibly it will fial on 1/1/10000000 but that needs testing.

To get the difference, use [Diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

If Diff doesn't work on your ranges, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/676828/486780 .

Comment: yeah it allowed. but the question is to find out difference between two dates in days.

Comment: Difference is easy. Expanded the answer. Ach, just noticed your point about diff in the question. If diff doesnt work, then you might have to do it manually.

Comment: Please Read the Question Properly.

Comment: Have a look at the SO link. That should be able to at least guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime may be able to store the date, but if you're using other helper functions they won't work, as they operate using basic types and not a more structured representation.  You're likely going to need to create your own utilities.